# How to put each string that a for loop outputs in a different variable in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net

so as the title states i want to know how I could have each of the strings given by a for loop that runs three times into a different variable for each.
It's meant to display a list of cards that are randomly generated and I want to get only the cards' values in the variable.

Console.WriteLine("You drew: ")

For count As Integer = 1 To 3
     Console.WriteLine("A " & GetCardValue() & GetSuit())
Next

Thank you.

Comment: Why not use [Array's](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/vb.net/vb.net_arrays.htm) for your problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can use a `List(Of T)` to store a variable number of items or an array to store fixed number of items. (Showing both in the same example, assuming that the card value is an Integer)

```
Dim valuesArray(3) As Integer
Dim valuesList As New List(Of Integer)

Console.WriteLine("You drew: ")
For count As Integer = 1 To 3
    Dim cardValue = GetCardValue()
    valuesArray(count) = cardValue
    valuesList.Add(cardValue)
    Console.WriteLine("A " & cardValue & GetSuit())
Next
```

Now, you can access the values with

```
Console.WriteLine(valuesArray(1))
Console.WriteLine(valuesArray(2))
Console.WriteLine(valuesArray(3))
```

or

```
Console.WriteLine(valuesList(0))
Console.WriteLine(valuesList(1))
Console.WriteLine(valuesList(2))
```

Both, array and list, start numbering the items with 0. Note that the array has a lenght of 4. We did not use `valuesArray(0)`.

You can also use for-each

```
For Each item In valuesArray
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

or

```
For Each item In valuesList
    Console.WriteLine(item)
Next
```

The iteration variable `item` is automatically declared and is limited to the for each loop. You can also specify the type explicitly `For Each item As Integer In valuesArray`